If 13 equal charges sit on the vertices of a 13-sided regular polygon and a charge, $Q$, lies at the center, what is the net force on charge $Q$?
I have not found a true formal answer to this question, so i decided to give it a try. My idea was to show that for any charge, $\large q_{i}$, there will exist adjacent charges $\large q_{j}$, $\large q_{j+1}$ such that $\large \overrightarrow{F}_{j} + \overrightarrow{F}_{j+1} = \overrightarrow{F}_{i}$.
Suppose $q_{i}$ is an arbitrary charge and let $q_{j}$ , $q_{j+1}$ be adjacent charges such that $\large\left( \overline{q_{i}O} \land \overline{O\lambda} \land \overline{q_{i} \lambda} \right)$, where $O$ is the center of the polygon, $\large \lambda$ is the mid point between $\large q_{j}$,  $\large q_{j+1}$ and $\large i\neq j\neq j+1$. Let $\large d$ be the distance between the adjacent charges and let $\large h$ be the length of  $\large \overline{O\lambda}$. Then, $\large \overrightarrow{F_{j}} =k\left(\frac{qQ}{r^{2}}\right)\overrightarrow{r}_{j}$ , for $\large \overrightarrow{r_{j}}=\left( \frac{d}{2}, h \right)$.  $\large\overrightarrow{F}_{j+1}=k\left(\frac{qQ}{r^{2}}\right)\overrightarrow{r}_{j+1}$ , for $\large r_{j+1} =\left(\frac{-d}{2}, h\right)$. Let $\large l=\sqrt{ \left(\frac{d}{2}\right)^{2}+h^{2}}$.  By coulombs law and the symmetry of the polygon, we let $\large \overrightarrow{F}_{i} = \overrightarrow{F}_{j} = \overrightarrow{F}_{\left( j+1\right)}$.
$\large \overrightarrow{F_{j_{x}}}=\overrightarrow{F_{j}}\cos\theta=\overrightarrow{F_{j}}\left(\frac{d}{2l}\right)$ ,  $\large \overrightarrow{F}_{\left( j+1\right)_{x}}=\overrightarrow{F}_{j+1}\cos\theta=\overrightarrow{F}_{j+1}\left(\frac{-d}{2l}\right)$. Thus,  $\large \sum_{F_{x}}=\overrightarrow{F}_{j_{x}}+\overrightarrow{F}_{\left(j+1\right)_{x}}= 0$.
$\large \overrightarrow{F}_{j_{y}}=\overrightarrow{F}_{j}\sin\theta=\overrightarrow{F}_{j}\left(\frac{h}{l}\right)$ ,  $\large \overrightarrow{F}_{\left(j+1\right)_{y}}=\overrightarrow{F}_{j+1}\sin\theta=\overrightarrow{F}_{j+1}\left( \frac{h}{l} \right)$. Thus, $\large\sum_{F_{y}}=\overrightarrow{F}_{j_{y}}+\overrightarrow{F}_{\left( j+1 \right)_{y}}=k\frac{qQ}{r^{2}}\left( \frac{h}{l} \right)\hat{y}$.
Thus, $\large \overrightarrow{F}_{j}+\overrightarrow{F}_{\left( j+1\right)}=2k\frac{qQh}{lr^{2}}\hat{y}$.
This is where i am confused as:
$\large \overrightarrow{F_{i}}=-\frac{qQ}{r^{2}}\hat{y}$
I know that the forces by the adjacent charges is equal and opposite to the forces by the $q_{i}$ charge. Why did i not a arrive at that conclusion?

Duplicate

The answer is supposed to be obvious by symmetry, without any calculation necessary.

@Ghoster sure, but the solutions provided are unintutive and overly complicated. By considering an arbitrary charge, you can make a general statement about them all, which is preferable to making individual statements about them all.

@Ghoster yes, but showing formally that its true is best and is good practice.

Why did i not a arrive at that conclusion? Because it’s not true. Have you drawn a force diagram?

showing formally that its true is best That’s your opinion, and you are certainly entitled to it, but I don’t share it.

the solutions provided are unintutive and overly complicated Summing a finite geometric series is not “overly complicated” (it’s usually taught in Algebra II) and IMHO  is much nicer than the calculations you’re doing which didn’t produce the right result. The answer in the duplicate question that does that sum, however, has a minor typo.
